# Install phpmyadmin on nginx

Tags: nginx

I try to install phpmyadmin to work with nginx in my archilnux box but I seem have some problem. The steps below is exactly what I've done :

```
sudo pacman -S phpmyadmin
```

Then I create a symbolic link use exactly like the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#NGINX_Configuration):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin /srv/http/<domain>/public_html/phpmyadmin
```

curl return :

```
curl -I http://localhost/phpmyadmin
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2011 16:57:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Connection: keep-alive
```

What I receive when I try to access through chromium :

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Error log :

```
2011/08/17 02:42:48 [error] 31015#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/) in /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/index.php on line 33
PHP Warning:  require_once(/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/index.php on line 33
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './libraries/common.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/index.php on line 33" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

I hope someone can help me about this problem :)

This is resolved by : add /usr/share/webapps to open_basedir in php.ini :)

Comment: With what problem?  What happens when you go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin in a browser?  That redirect adds a / which is probably valid.

Comment: I just update my post above :)

Comment: Okay, so next step, post the error log from nginx.

Comment: edited and add log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think it's pretty clear,

> 2011/08/17 02:42:48 [error] 31015#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   **File(/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php) is not
>   within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/)**
>   in /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/index.php on line 33

As per Martin F's comment - check your php-fpm or php.ini settings to make sure it can execute stuff in that path.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify the problem. I hope I can resolve this one, I will update.

Comment: It's not in the nginx config. Nginx neither embeds nor configures PHP, it simply sends requests to it via fastcgi. You need to configure this in either php-fpm or in your php.ini.