# Configuring phpMyAdmin with nginx (Fedora 17) for access at localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, nginx, fedora

[Tried all answers on Stackoverflow, and searched on google a lot, but none of the configurations worked.]

I've installed LEMP server on Fedora using the guide on DigitalOcean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6). Replaced example.com in nginx's default.conf to localhost.

Then, I installed phpMyAdmin using this (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server).

The nginx web directory is */usr/share/nginx/html*. I've created a symbolic link for phpmyadmin. It's at */usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin*.

Currently, I just need localhost access (*localhost/phpmyadmin*). I'm able to access localhost, and localhost/info.php.

I tried many configurations, one of them below: Nginx location directive doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

But it doesn't work. Sometimes I get "No input file specified." and other times 404 not found. I'd like to have the access at *localhost/phpmyadmin*.

Edit:
My default.conf file. Getting a "No input file specified." error in browser.

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    #listen       80 default_server;
    listen  80;
    server_name localhost;
    #server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ /phpMyAdmin/.*\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/$uri;
        include     fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your current nginx config for review?

Comment: Added the conf file.

Comment: Does http://localhost/phpMyAdmin (watch out for case) work? You alias the mixed-case version for static files (`location /phpmyadmin`), but not for the `location /phpMyAdmin/.*\.php$` block.  You should also have a look at the **permissions** for the _real_ phpMyAdmin directory.

Comment: localhost/phpMyAdmin gives an internal 500 server error.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Permissions for the real phpMyAdmin directory (in /usr/share/) are: 
drwxr-xr-x.    8 root root  4096 Mar 16 17:31 phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `404`, you should make the character cases match either all `phpmyadmin` (all lower case) or `phpMyAdmin`.

To make the config clearer (my opinion), you could use nested `location`s:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/$uri;
        include     fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

You then have to relink `phpMyAdmin` in your webroot (note the missing `alias` directive):

```
unlink /usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin
ln -s /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin
```

---

**Alternatively**, to keep the mixed-case link, add this line to the above `location /phpmyadmin` to internally change the `$uri` (required to find the files):

```
rewrite ^/phpmyadmin(.*)$ /phpMyAdmin$1;
```

---

To fix the `500`, you might want to check out [another answer on SF about PHP restrictions](https://serverfault.com/a/301765/138732). I just now realized that executing PHP scripts outside the webroot can trigger security mechanisms.
That would then be a PHP error, meaning that the `location` matches.

Comment: Hi, I tried your config above (except for the rewrite statement). Looks like the location matches now, but I'm getting the following error. 

phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

Comment: Hey,
I'm now able to access phpmyadmin. But it still looks like something is not right, I'm unable to create database or add/edit users, the request keeps going on if I click Create button to create a db.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I finally figured out the problem. The auth_type in /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php was set to http. I set it to cookie, and changed ownership of /var/lib/php/session to nginx:nginx. Now, it works. Thanks a lot.